# Find mongo document - Array of documents with nested array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents with the following structure:

```
{_id: "28", cds: [{name: "myname", issue:["i1", "i2", "i3"]}]
```

How to find all documents where cds.issue[*] == "i3" for example?
In other words where there is a string "i3" in the issue array.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy to achieve using Mongo' [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
db.collection.find({"cds.issue": "i3"})
```